# 'Tips for golfing' questions: on the main site or on meta?

Tags: discussion

Today someone posted [a 'tips for golfing' question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21676/visual-studio-settings-for-c-code-golfing). Some people think it should be posted on Meta, and other people think it should be posted on the Main site.

So, where should we actually post 'tips for golfing' questions? On the main site or on Meta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tips-for-golfing questions belong on the main site, but should be community wiki.

Answer (score -2):

Tips-for-golfing questions belong on meta, because they are questions about how best to answer questions. Questions about questions are metaquestions.